# How do I get check state of the checkbox on the List control Header?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I am having a property sheet where in the second page I am having a listcontrol where that list control contains checkbox to each item.And for the first header I added a checkbox image on the column header.When I click on the checkbox on the column header then state of all the checkboxe's are changing in according to the column header checkbox.When I click on any item in the list control I am enabling the wizard buttons,if nothing is selected Next and back buttons will be disabled.Till this point everything is ok.But as I told you that I added a checkbox image on to the column header ,now if I click on the column header all the items in the list control will get check state and again I click on the column header checkbox now all the items in the list control will get unchecked.

As I told you depending on the check state I am enabling the wizard button,Now for this header I added an event in a class derived from "CHeaderCtrl" -"HDN_ITEMCLICK" ,when I click on the header it is comming to this event handler ,but from here how can I disable the wizard buttons depending on the header check state in that event.

```
//Second page where it does contain the list control.
//A class is derived from cListCtrl
//A class is derived from CHeaderCtrl

//In Page Class
BOOL OnInitDialog()
{
  CPropertyPage::OnInitDialog();
  m_listCtrl.Init();//CCheckListCtrl m_listCtrl ;
}
void CMFPSearchListView::OnItemClick(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
LPNMITEMACTIVATE pNMItemActivate = reinterpret_cast<LPNMITEMACTIVATE>(pNMHDR);
int list_row;
list_row = pNMItemActivate->iItem;
int list_col ;
list_col = pNMItemActivate->iSubItem;
int listcount = m_listCtrl.GetItemCount();
BOOL bRet = m_listCtrl.GetCheck(list_row);  
if(TRUE != bRet)
{

    CPropertySheet *TestSheet = (CPropertySheet*)GetParent();
    TestSheet->SetWizardButtons(PSWIZB_NEXT|PSWIZB_BACK);
}
else
{
            //Here I am setting the wizard buttons depending on the Item Check state
    CPropertySheet *TestSheet = (CPropertySheet*)GetParent();
    TestSheet->SetWizardButtons(PSWIZB_CANCEL);
}


*pResult = 0;
}

//In the CCheckListCtrl class(derived from ClistCtrl)
//LVN_ITEMCHANGED

void CCheckListCtrl::OnLvnItemchanged(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
NMLISTVIEW* pNMLV = (NMLISTVIEW*)pNMHDR;
int row ;
row = pNMLV->iItem;
int col ;
col = pNMLV->iSubItem;
*pResult = 0;

if ( m_blInited && LVIF_STATE == pNMLV->uChanged)
{
    BOOL blAllChecked = TRUE;
    int nCount = GetItemCount();
    for(int nItem = 0; nItem < nCount; nItem++)
    {
        if ( !ListView_GetCheckState(GetSafeHwnd(), nItem) )
        {
            blAllChecked = FALSE;
            break;
        }
    }

    HDITEM hdItem;
    hdItem.mask = HDI_IMAGE;
    if (blAllChecked)
        hdItem.iImage = 2;//0;//2;
    else
        hdItem.iImage = 1;
    VERIFY( m_checkHeadCtrl.SetItem(0, &hdItem) );
}

*pResult = 0;
}
BOOL CCheckListCtrl::Init()
{
if (m_blInited)
    return TRUE;

HINSTANCE hBmpInst = ::LoadLibrary(L"BmpRes.dll");
AfxSetResourceHandle(hBmpInst);
CHeaderCtrl* pHeadCtrl = this->GetHeaderCtrl();
ASSERT(pHeadCtrl->GetSafeHwnd());

VERIFY( m_checkHeadCtrl.SubclassWindow(pHeadCtrl->GetSafeHwnd()) );

INT ImgRet = m_checkImgList->Create(IDB_BMP_CHECKBOX_STATE, 16, 2, RGB(255,0,255)) ;
int i = m_checkImgList->GetImageCount();
m_checkHeadCtrl.SetImageList(m_checkImgList);

HDITEM hdItem;
hdItem.mask = HDI_IMAGE | HDI_FORMAT;
VERIFY( m_checkHeadCtrl.GetItem(0, &hdItem) );
hdItem.iImage = 1;
hdItem.fmt |= HDF_IMAGE;

VERIFY( m_checkHeadCtrl.SetItem(0, &hdItem) );

m_blInited = TRUE;
if(NULL!=hBmpInst)
{  
   ::FreeLibrary(hBmpInst);
   hBmpInst=NULL;
}
return TRUE;
}
//In CheckHeaderCtrl class (derived from CHeaderCtrl)
//HDN_ITEMCLICK
void CCheckHeadCtrl::OnHdnItemclick(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
NMHEADER* pNMHead = (NMHEADER*)pNMHDR;
*pResult = 0;

int nItem = pNMHead->iItem;
if (0 != nItem)
    return;

HDITEM hdItem;
hdItem.mask = HDI_IMAGE;
VERIFY( GetItem(nItem, &hdItem) );

if (hdItem.iImage == 1)
    hdItem.iImage = 2;
else
    hdItem.iImage = 1;

VERIFY( SetItem(nItem, &hdItem) );

BOOL bl = hdItem.iImage == 2 ? TRUE : FALSE;
CListCtrl* pListCtrl = (CListCtrl*)GetParent();
int nCount = pListCtrl->GetItemCount(); 
for(nItem = 0; nItem < nCount; nItem++)
{
    ListView_SetCheckState(pListCtrl->GetSafeHwnd(), nItem, bl);
}
*pResult = 0;
}
```

You can observe that all these are implemented three different classes for listcontrol,Headerctrl and propertypage.If you can see in propertypage you can observe OnItemClick event I was setting the wizard buttons,similarly I have to set when the OnHdnItemclick event is called.While debugging it is hitting on the OnHdnItemclick when I click on the header and next it is hitting at OnLvnItemChanged ,But not coming to my page class ,Can anyone please help me ,how can I set the wizard buttons on the header click event.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `HDITEM` information from the clicked column of the header control by using [CHeaderCtrl::GetItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/82shyz02.aspx).

Once you have that, you need to check if the mask has the `HDI_FORMAT` bit set and, assuming it does (which means that the `fmt` member has valid data), look for the `HDF_CHECKED` flag in the `fmt` member of the `HDITEM` structure to determine if the checkbox is checked.

So in pseudo-code'ish:

```
HDITEM pItem;
m_pHdrCtrl->GetItem(0, &pItem);

if ((pItem.mask & HDI_FORMAT) != 0 && (pItem.fmt & HDF_CHECKED) != 0)
    // header checkbox is checked
else
    // header checkbox is not checked
```

Comment: @user2713353 That's difficult to say, because you didn't show your own code ;-)

Comment: @user2713353 You said you have an event handler for a click on the header, so if that's where you need to check it, that's where to put the code.

Comment: I modified my original post and added code what I had actually done.Can you please have a look and guide me out to the right path. :-)

Comment: @user2713353 In your function `CCheckHeadCtrl::OnHdnItemclick` you already have `HDITEM` so you just need to do whatever you want using the `if` statement in my answer (just replace `pItem` with `hdItem` to match your variable names).

Comment: I tried doing so ,But I am unable to set the wizard buttons.That is only the issue,under the hood of "if"block I added the wizard buttons if(1 == pItem.Image){ CPropertySheet* pMySheet = (CPropertySheet*)GetParent; pMySheet->SetWizardButton(PSWIZB_BACK)} ;else{pMySheet->SetWizardButton(PSWIZB_NEXT)};This is how I had set ,but still I am not getting the expected behaviour.

Comment: @user2713353 Your question was *"How do I get check state of the checkbox on the list control-header"*, which it seems I've answered. If you have a new question, you need to ask it separately ....